MoveGroup ROS2 : Control Robot through ROS1Bridge
I'm starting my master thesis with ROS2. It's about screw dismantling based on some DNN for screw detection.
Inside the controller of the robot I'm using (6dof), there is roscore running as soon as the robot control is powered on.
Hence, I cannot edit/ change anything. It's embedded in their OS I guess.
The bad part is: It's running on melodic. I've already managed to create a custom URDF file and to create a moveit config package based on that. I changed the name of the controller to the name I can see in rostopic list. That worked. I could start Rviz+MoveitPlanningPlugin and move around. Fine.
Now I'm trying to do the same but for ROS2 and there things get tricky.
I guess there are 2 different approaches:

Running move_group node in ros2 directly via rosbridge
Running move_group in noetic and then using rosebridge

I'm trying variant 1 for now.
I've created the Description Package again and derived a moveit config package.
Changed the moveit_controllers.yaml file like this:
moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager

moveit_simple_controller_manager:
  controller_names:
    - neura/joint_trajectory_arm_controller

  neura/joint_trajectory_arm_controller:
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: true
    joints:
      - lara8_joint1
      - lara8_joint2
      - lara8_joint3
      - lara8_joint4
      - lara8_joint5
      - lara8_joint6

This corresponds to the naming I setup for ROS Noetic:
# Simulation settings for using moveit_sim_controllers
moveit_sim_hw_interface:
  joint_model_group: manipulator
  joint_model_group_pose: up
# Settings for ros_control_boilerplate control loop
generic_hw_control_loop:
  loop_hz: 300
  cycle_time_error_threshold: 0.01
# Settings for ros_control hardware interface
hardware_interface:
  joints:
    - lara8_joint1
    - lara8_joint2
    - lara8_joint3
    - lara8_joint4
    - lara8_joint5
    - lara8_joint6
  sim_control_mode: 1  # 0: position, 1: velocity
# Publish all joint states
# Creates the /joint_states topic necessary in ROS
joint_state_controller:
  type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
  publish_rate: 50
controller_list:
  - name: neura/joint_trajectory_arm_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    default: True
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - lara8_joint1
      - lara8_joint2
      - lara8_joint3
      - lara8_joint4
      - lara8_joint5
      - lara8_joint6

BTW: The Ros bridge seems to be working, if i echo /joint_states, I get output.
I've started it with ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge --bridge-all-topics so that it should work for every topic.
If I start move_group.launch.py from my custom moveit package, at the end it states that ** You can start planning now!** in green. I start RViz2 and add the MotionPlanning Plugin, but I cannot see the robot or anything.
So my question is more high-level: How would you approach it and what are the things to look for? The first or rather the second where I run move_group in ros1 and try to communicate between that node via the rosbridge?
